# Compile .NET console app as single executable

Tags: .net, visual-studio, compilation, f#

I have a console app written in F# targeting .NET Framework 4.6.2. The artifacts of my build are MyApp.exe and FSharp.Core.dll. This page https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/compiler-options suggests that the `—-standalone` flag should allow me to produce a stand-alone MyApp.exe. How do I do that in Visual Studio (2017) or through some other means?

Comment: You just pass the `--standalone` flag to the compiler. I don't quite understand what the specific difficulty is.

Comment: I couldn’t figure out where to put the flag and whether it needed the --.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Visual Studio, you can right-click on the project, go to properties and specify `--standalone` in "Other flags". The following screenshot is from VS2015, but I think this looks the same in VS2017.

Also, if you are using both Debug and Release builds, you will need to specify this for both of them.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Right-click on the project, select Properties, select Build, in the ‘Other flags’ field enter `--standalone`.